# jquery jstree changes icons for @media (max-width: 768px)

Tags: jquery, jstree

Why does jstree change the icons when the browser window resizes to 768px?

This even happens on the jstree site. How can I disable this without adjusting the css by hand?

open the site http://www.jstree.com/ and reduce your browser size to see it

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Okay so I did this in `themes/default/style.css`

```
//@media (max-width: 768px) {
@media handheld {
```

as my site only needs to work for desktops